# clip-path not working on safari even when using webkit prefix

Tags: javascript, css, svg

So basically, I am pasting my jsfiddle so that it's easier for you to figure out what's really going on.

https://jsfiddle.net/h608n5yj/2/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> 
</head>

<style>
    .avatar-small {
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
        padding: 4px;
    }
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        clip-path: url('#avatar-mask');
        -webkit-clip-path: url('#avatar-mask')
    }

    .avatar { 
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #9f7d5a, #d4b380 17%, #eecf97 41%, #b89a6a 62%, #dabd85 83%, #d4b380 100%);
        clip-path: url('#avatar-mask');
        -webkit-clip-path: url('#avatar-mask');
    }
</style>

<body>
    <svg>
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="avatar-mask" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
                <path d="M .5 0 C .1 0 0 .1 0 .5 0 .9 .1 1 .5 1 .9 1 1 .9 1 .5 1 .1 .9 0 .5 0 Z" />
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
    </svg>
    <div class="avatar avatar-small">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/gycB3mQ/avatar.png">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Just open this link on chrome first and then Safari. you will realize that there's a difference(look at the background of the image). This makes me believe that `clip-path` not working on safari even when using `webkit` prefix.

What's wrong? Any ideas? I am not comfortable with `SVG` that much so that I might understand this, so i'd appreciate if you could give me the code which fixes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the SVG inside mask

```css
.avatar-small {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 4px;
}
.avatar-big {
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  padding: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.avatar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #9f7d5a, #d4b380 17%, #eecf97 41%, #b89a6a 62%, #dabd85 83%, #d4b380 100%);
}
.mask,
.mask > *{
  -webkit-mask: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1 1"> <path d="M .5 0 C .1 0 0 .1 0 .5 0 .9 .1 1 .5 1 .9 1 1 .9 1 .5 1 .1 .9 0 .5 0 Z" /></svg>');
          mask: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1 1"> <path d="M .5 0 C .1 0 0 .1 0 .5 0 .9 .1 1 .5 1 .9 1 1 .9 1 .5 1 .1 .9 0 .5 0 Z" /></svg>');

}
```

```html
<div class="avatar avatar-small mask">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/gycB3mQ/avatar.png">
</div>
<div class="avatar avatar-big mask">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/gycB3mQ/avatar.png">
</div>
```

Comment: let me know if it's fine on Safari